# Display array words one by one when press enter in java netbeans

Tags: java, arrays, netbeans

I want to know how to display each single array data one by one when only press enter . Which means When I press enter button output need to show me the 1st array data then when I press 2nd time pressing enter need to show me the 2nd data from the arraylist ? how to do it ?

Comment: Do you mean NetBeans code complete, its debugger, or just a normal java array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static void print() throws IOException {
  char w[] = {'h','e','l','l','o'};

  for (int i = 0; i < w.length; i++) {
    char c = (char) System.in.read();
    if(c == 13)
        continue;

    System.out.println(w[i]);
  }
}
```

you can do the same with ArrayList or other kind of collections